# actionscript not adding child and not recognizing child Moviecip symbol errors. 1046,1180,1120

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I simply have two Classes

1. Document class
2. Movie clip class named type

Document class simply adds the child
and that symbol is declared too

it gives error when i declare the symbol in Document Class:

```
var field:texts = new texts();
    addChild(field);
```

There is also another child which when without this upper piece shows up on stage:

```
var button:graphic = new graphic();
    addChild(button);
```

The errors are:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: texts.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method texts.
```

NOTE : This code is all from document class i did not share symbol class as i am sure that the code is correct

The imports for document class are:

```
   import flash.text.TextField;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.display.BitmapData;
   import flash.display.Bitmap;
   import flash.display.SimpleButton;
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors mean the compiler is not finding your `texts` class.

If the `texts` class is an ActionScript class (.as file) then make sure it is in the same package as the Document class. If not, you'll need to import it. Also make sure the class name is spelled the same with the same capitalization as you are using when you instantiate it.

If it is just symbol from the library, make sure you are exporting it for ActionScript (Symbol Properties > Export for ActionScript). Check 'Export in Frame 1'. Check the linkage class name to make sure it matches what you are using to instantiate it.